# ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sections' of null

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I tried everything and this is still not working. I don't know what is causing this error. When uglify js is commented out it compiles without problems.

**webpack.config**

```
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
// http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: '"production"',
        },
    }),

     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
         compress: {
            warnings: false,
        },
     }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
    }),
    ]);
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
"presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-3",
    [ "env", { "modules": false } ]
]
}
```

**script**

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules
```

If anyone can help it would be awesome.

Comment: I think it would help if you specify which version of webpack and uglify plugin you are using, what would also help is to know which command you use when building?

Comment: @chrisweb webpack-3.6.0, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-1.2.4

Comment: @lejhbah any update on this?